# Do the scope of a function is the entire program if declared at the top level, but not with

Tags: javascript

Is the scope of a function is the function in which it is declared, or the entire program if it is declared at the top level, as such using the following syntax order:

```
 function funcName(parameter) {statement;
return;}
```

And not:

```
  var varName = function(parameter) {statement;

return;}
```

I can't ask anymore question because of the three I ask was low grade it said, so I'mmma use the post question I already ask to ask my question. If that's not okay please tell me. I wish not to get banned. Should have an area on here for low grade question.

Comment: There's no `for each` (or `foreach()`) construct in Javascript; use only `for (var in obj)`.

Comment: Also, note that `var` scopes to a function, not a set of `{}`, so putting it in a loop statement like that may lead to confusion and bugs (read up on "hoisting").

Comment: please re read it again.

Comment: It's deprecated feature. It might not present in your javascript interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others you don't need `each` to loop properties. Also looks like you want to sum values (not keys):

```
var item;
for (item in obj) { // loop by property names (keys)
  sum += obj[item];
}
```

Comment: MDN also [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) it's deprecated. You probably has the error because your javascript engine doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a `for each` loop, it's just `for (x in y)`